# Pointers in c++ and runtime errors

Tags: c++

What is the issue with this code? It gives the output as expected, but there is a runtime error, and I don't know what it is.

Can somebody explain the concept behind it?

```
int main()
{
    int *a = new int(7);//assume the heap memory has address 4F
    int *p;
    p = a;
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << p << endl;
    cout << *a << endl;
    cout << *p << endl;
    *p = 10;
    cout << *a << endl;
    delete p;
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always use exactly one delete for each new

Comment: `p` is equal to `a`, which contains the result of `new int(7)`.   Doing `delete p` followed by `delete a` therefore releases the same dynamically allocated `int` twice .  That causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reassigned `*p = 10` but `a` and `p` are still the same address in memory. As already mentioned, you are trying to delete the same memory space twice, which can explain the runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the fact that `a` and `p` point to the same object, and so by doing

```
delete p;
delete a;
```

You are deleting 2 times the same object, and so the second time you are trying to delete memory that is already been freed